# How to perform polynomial long division on 1/(1 - x)?

Tags: polynomials, generating-functions

How do I perform polynomial long division on $\frac{1}{1 - x}$ to obtain the sequence $1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots$?

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-drdeNMoe8w) video, the teacher went about it in the following way...

$$
\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{r}
 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots \\ 
 1 - x \enclose{longdiv}{\hspace{10pt}1\hspace{85.5pt}} \\
 \underline{-\left(1 - x\right)}\hspace{64.5pt} \\
 x\hspace{68.5pt} \\
 \underline{-\left(x - x^2\right)}\hspace{42pt} \\
 x^2\hspace{46.5pt} \\
 \vdots\hspace{52.5pt}
\end{array}
$$

I have always performed polynomial long division wrt the term of highest degree, e.g., to find $\frac{-7 + 5x + x^2}{-1 + 2x}$, I would do the following...

$$
\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{r}
 x^2 + 5x \hspace{4pt}- 7\hspace{33pt} \\ 
 2x - 1 \enclose{longdiv}{\hspace{10pt}2x^3 + 9x^2 - 19x + 7\hspace{4pt}} \\
 \underline{-\left(2x^3 - x^2\right)}\hspace{50.5pt} \\
 10x^2 - 19x + 7\hspace{4pt} \\
 \underline{-\left(10x^2 - 5x\right)}\hspace{21.5pt} \\
 -14x + 7\hspace{4pt} \\
 \underline{-\left(-14x + 7\right)}\hspace{0pt} \\
 0\hspace{4pt} \\
\end{array}
$$

When should I use the teachers variation of the conventional method?

Comment: Technically the video is not about division of polynomials. Rather the division takes place in the ring of formal power series. Depends on your background how much that makes sense to you.. Anyway, the generating functions typically reside in that ring of formal power series, so it may be a good time to familiarize yourself with [them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it when $x$ is small compared to $1$.  That is not as silly a remark as it sounds like it is.  If you stop the video's approach part way through you get a remainder term just like you might with the top down approach.  You could write $$\frac 1{1-x}=1+x+x^2+\frac {x^3}{1-x}$$
This is an algebraic fact, valid for all values of $x$ except $x=1$.  When you keep going you get an infinite sum on the right, which is useful as long as it converges.  It converges when $|x| \lt 1$.  If $|x| \ll 1$ the sum converges quickly and you can decide when the error committed by truncating it is acceptable.

In some problems you know that $x$ is small, in which case this is quite useful.

If the division is going to come out even, you can do it either way around.  Taking your example
$$\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{r}
 -7 + 5x \hspace{4pt}+x^2\hspace{33pt} \\ 
 -1+2x \enclose{longdiv}{\hspace{10pt}7-19x+9x^2+2x^3\hspace{4pt}} \\
 \underline{7-14x}\hspace{30.5pt} \\
 \hspace {30 pt}- 5x+9x^2\hspace{4pt} \\
 \underline{- 5x+10x^2}\hspace{21.5pt} \\
 -x^2 + 2x^3\hspace{4pt} \\
 \underline{-x^2+2x^3}\hspace{0pt} \\
 0\hspace{4pt} \\
\end{array}$$
where I can't get the spacing as nice as you did, but it gives the same result.

Comment: What do you mean by "division is going to come out even"? As in a remainder of 0?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  In your example, both approaches give us the same  factorization of the cubic

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure how useful this is. Yes, you explain a number of things. But, I'm uncomfortable with statements like *$x$ is small comparede to $1$*. The question was framed in the context of generating functions. So the result of the division is a formal power series. Meaning that $x$ does not take any values at all, real or other. Powers of $x$ are just placeholders for the entities of the sequence that this is a generating function of.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at it. Start with the known formulas:
$$\begin{align}1-x^2&=(1-x)(1+x)\\
1-x^3&=(1-x)(1+x+x^2)\\
1-x^4&=(1-x)(1+x+x^2+x^3)\\
&\ \ \vdots\\
1-x^n&=(1-x)(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^{n-1}) \Rightarrow \\
\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}&=1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots +x^{n-1}\end{align}$$
If $|x|<1$ and $n\to \infty$, then $x^n\to 0$ and you get the relation:
$$\frac1{1-x}=1+x+x^3+x^4+\cdots$$

Comment: When you perform "usual" long division of polynomials, your division is "centered at infinity" in the sense that your remainders are negligible compared to the divisor at infinity (remainders have lesser degree). In this case  the division is "centered at zero" and your remainders become smaller and smaller as $x\to 0$. Thus, their degrees keep increasing in the process.